# Alternative to partitioning in SQL Server 2016 on memory optimized tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

I have a script in existing SQL Server 2012 to delete old/expired sessions using partitioning. Data is moved from the source table to the staging table on basis of weekday partition and truncate operation is performed on the source table.

After migration to SQL Server 2016, partition and truncate is not supported on memory-optimized tables. What is the best solution to deal with this?

Comment: How can we perform delete operation without locking the table

Comment: why would an in-memory table require partitioning. Rethink your design!  Partition switching is typically a warehouse OLAP technique; in-memory tables are typically used for OLTP....